# Choose the correct options from the following options given...

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I know that $f$ is strictly monotone. Please give some hint from this.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=e^x+x$.

Comment: @ Zerox, Is it counterexample?

Comment: "for every $n$" means "for every $n\in\Bbb N$"?

Comment: @gygug123 The counterexample of b, c and the example of d.

Answer (score 1):

No, No, No, Yes: Consider
$$ f(x)=\max\{x,x^3\}+1.$$